# Computing Median. Where is the error?

Tags: r, median

I want to compute median of the following density. But it's not working.

```
  f <- function(x)(3/7)*x^2

  r <- rep(0,5000)
  x=seq(1,2,length=5000)

 for(i in 1:5000){
    r[i]=integrate(f,lower=1,upper=x[i])$value
  }

 d <- data.frame(x,r)
 med <- d$x[d$r==0.5]
 med
```

Comment: You need to explain what you expected it to do.

Comment: @joran I have edited my question. please, review it.

Comment: So for this density you could just write down the answer directly.  Why do a computation at all?  Is this just a toy example?  Or a homework problem?

Comment: @Aaron Is it forbidden to ask question in `stack overflow` related to homework if one shows his/her effort ?

Comment: No, not forbidden.  But context is important.  In this case, you shouldn't get the answer in the way you are attempting, you should simply integrate.  Unless there's some context you're not telling us.

Comment: @Aaron oh i see. Now it is clear. S/he should add some context to make it clear to everyone. Thanks.

Comment: Also see this [meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No elements of `d$r` equal **exactly** 0.5.
I suspect that you need something like:

```
med <- d$x[d$r>=0.5 & d$r <=0.501]
```